# How to refer a number in a list with two columns, first one is a number and the second one is empty?

Tags: list-manipulation, number-representation

Let's say, I have defined a list as

```
list = {{-31, -31}, {52, }, {34, -11}, {-38, }, {78, -44}, {-36,14}, {-9, 98}, {33, 6}, {82, 99}, {-85, -10}}
```

As you can see, the second and the fourth element do not have data in their second place. I want to use `DeleteCases` command to delete these rows. If I split this data as,

```
a = data[[All,1]]
{-31, 52, 34, -38, 78, -36, -9, 33, 82, -85}
b = data[[All,2]]
{-31, Null, -11, Null, -44, 14, 98, 6, 99, -10}
```

`DeleteCases[b,""]` command can delete Null elements in b. But I want to delete the elements with the empty space from my original list using `DeleteCases`. How should I refer the first element,which is a number, in my list?

`DeleteCases[list,(What should be here?)]` I don't know what to do? Should I use something else? As you can see, I am a newbie.

Comment: simply `DeleteCases[list, {_,}]`

Comment: `Select[list, NumberQ[#[[2]]] &]`

Comment: `list /. {_, Null} :> Nothing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[list, {___, Null, ___}]
DeleteCases[list, {___, , ___}]
```

Also with `Select` and `ContainsAny`.

```
Select[Not@*ContainsAny[{Null}]]@list
```